# ios app stuck in launchscreen when click on inactive push notification in xamarin form ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm working in Xamarin form ios. My issue is when click on push notification received when its inactive/killed,then its stuck in launchscreen.

I have implemented Video as splash screen.

**the scenario for the issue is,**
step 1)launch the app..  Click on received notification(foreground)-> it will redirect to specific page(ex notification list page).
step 2)now close the app, Click on received notification(inactive)-> open the app with white screen and stuck....
or
step 2) close the app, once got the inactive push notification then directly click on app icon , it will stuck

**when it work :**
if I don't click on foreground push notification(step 1) , and only click on inactive push notification then its work fine.(redirecting to notification list page).

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` before you start playing video:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
    self.startPlayingVideo()
})
```